# Modulus if else count misleading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
function expand(div_block_id, expansion_class, original_class, time, callback_function_original, callback_function_expand) {
        console.log("entered expand");
        var id = '#' + div_block_id; //ID received by function
        counter = counters[div_block_id + '_counter']; //Associates the counter per div block respectively 

        //Original ID of style
        $(id).click(function () {
            console.log("entered expand on click");
            //If the click counter is even then animate back to original state
            $("#dialog").remove();
            console.log(counter);
            if (++counter % 2 == 0) {
                console.log('counter =>'+counter);
                console.log('counter array index value ='+ counters[div_block_id + '_counter']);
                counters[div_block_id + '_counter'] = counter;
                console.log("entered expand if");
                $(this).animate(original_class, {
                    duration: time, //animation duration
                    start: callback_function_original //make animation happen symultaneously with callback
                });
                console.log("animated original class");
                console.log(counters);
            } else {
                //++counter;
                counters[div_block_id + '_counter'] = counter;
                console.log("entered expand else");
                //Expand to desired css
                $(this).animate(expansion_class, {
                    duration: time,
                    start: callback_function_expand //make animation happen symultaneously with callback
                });
                console.log("animated expand class");
                console.log(div_block_id + '=' + counters[div_block_id + '_counter']);
                //Reset counter on every uneven click so it wont get bigger
                //counters[div_block_id + '_counter'] = 0;
            }
            console.log("exited expand");
        });
    };
}
```

I have a basic if else case where it suppose to detect even and odd clicks

```
$(id).click(function(){
     if(++counter % 2 == 0){
        ...add some animations
     }else{
       do some other animation
     }
```

but when I open two or more divs the counter loses its count, but the array shows otherwise when I see the console. All I want to do is to click on any div and if the main div it's open then you can expand that div, but if you close the main div with the other divs opened all of them should close.

I know it's a bit hard to get it, you can see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wqKt/3/)

Comment: have you tried removing `counter` into the global scope where it doesn't get re-initialised everytime the `expand` function is called

Comment: The thing is that it changes depending on which div is clicked, so I think it should be called every time there's a click in a different div

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it is that is suppose to be happening in the fiddle, I click and it opens, after that nothing else happens, sometimes it will close...

Comment: Exactly, its suppose to open and if you click on `Product Development and introduction process` its suppose to expand but it does it only when it wants to